# Multiple migrations in django south

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I couldn't find a clear cut answer to this via google or the south docs, so i'm posting it here.

I've been using south for a while to manage my django models, however, until now i've always done one migration, pushed to the production server and migrated on there as well. I was wondering, is it possible to do multiple migrations on the production server at the same time?

For example, if i create multiple migrations on my dev server (that were migrated only on the dev server), if i push the migrations via git and run migrate AppName, will it run all the migrations its missing? or just the most recent one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South keeps track of the migrations that were done in a history table.

In your production environment database, it will reflect the migrations you have done in there and once you push one or more new migrations and run `migrate`, it will check your migrations against the history table and do the necessary.

Answer (score 0):

South will run all the remaining migrations.